# Write template function that accepts mutable span as an immutable span

Tags: c++

A [gsl::span](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/docs/gsl-intro.md) is view of a piece of memory.

`foo` is a template function that can accept either a mutable span and an immutable span.

I want the code within `foo` to always only have immutable access to the piece memory.

```
#include <gsl/gsl>  // gsl-lite

template <typename T>
void foo(gsl::span<const T> x) {}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto s1 = gsl::span<int>(arr);
    foo(s1);
}
```

This doesn't work because no type conversion during template instantiation.

If I write the following instead:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(gsl::span<T> x) {}
```

Within `foo`, `x` can be a mutable span.

What is the correct fix for this use case?

Comment: Don't you just need `gsl::span<T> x`?

Comment: @NathanOliver When that accepts a `gsl::span<int>`, `x` is a mutable span instead of an immutable span... Is the use case realistic?

Comment: Ah, you want the span to be immutable in the function, not just take an immutable span if you get one.

Comment: @NathanOliver yea.

Comment: The easiest way probably is to write a second overload taking `gsl::span<T>`. It can just call the original function, after casting the parameter.

Comment: How to write that overload? Sorry if I miss something basic because I learn c++ on my own. I tried `template <typename T>
void foo(gsl::span<T> x) { foo<const T>(x); }` But that gives segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsl::span<const T>` has constructor accepting `gsl::span<T>`. So you "just" have an issue of template deduction.

You have several ways to workaround your issue:

- Be explicit at call site:

  - call `foo<int>(arr)`
  - or call `foo(gsl::span<const int>(arr))`
- Write overloads:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  void foo(gsl::span<const T> arr) { /* Your implementation */ }

  template <typename T>
  void foo(gsl::span<T> arr) { foo(gsl::span<const T>(arr)); }
  ```
- Write helper functions to be less explicit at call site, for example:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  span<const T> as_immutable_view(span<T> s) { return s; }
  ```

  and then call `foo(as_immutable_view(arr))`

Answer (score 1):

How about just making a const version of the variable out of the parameter?

```
template <typename T>
void foo(gsl::span<T> x_raw)
{
   gsl::span<const T> x { x_raw }; // add const if not already present
   // use x in the code
}
```